# Inserting into treeview rows from MS SQL server database in python using tkinter

Tags: python, sql-server, for-loop, insert, treeview

I wrote this code and it gives me the error shown in the screenshot below the code.
the text in each cell of the table is shown with its quotes and comman mark.

I searched google and all I got is nothing concerning this problem, I even didn't see anyone faced it whether on YouTube or here. This is my first try so I don't understand where is the problem, basically.

I'm trying to make a very simple UI to display the contents (records) of a table in a database in a table created using treeview in tkinter through connection to MS SQL Server. When I insert using `.insert('', 'end', values=i)` in the for loop, I get the record tabulated with their bracket symbols and quotes and comma symbols.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pyodbc

####### Defining functions #######

def update(rows):
    for i in rows:
        trv.insert('', 'end', values=i)

#### connecting to the the Microsoft SQL server ####
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-7IKK3PQ;'
                      'Database=HospAnalyDepart;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

#activating the object for database queries
cursor = conn.cursor()
#------------------------------------------------

### creating window ###
root = Tk()

#creating labeled frames
wrapper1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Patients")
wrapper2 = LabelFrame(root, text="Search")
wrapper3 = LabelFrame(root, text="Patient Data")

wrapper1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=20)
wrapper2.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=10)
wrapper3.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=20)
#---------------------------------------------------------

#creating the table as a tree view
trv = ttk.Treeview(wrapper1, columns=(1,2,3,4), show="headings", height="6")
trv.pack()

#naming headings
trv.heading(1, text="Patient ID")
trv.heading(2, text="Gender")
trv.heading(3, text="Age")
trv.heading(4, text="Mobile")

#tabel content from the db
query = "SELECT PatientId, Gender, Age, Mobile FROM Patients"
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
update(rows)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


root.title("My Application")
root.geometry("1050x700")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the following:

```
def update(rows):
    for i in rows:
        trv.insert('', 'end', values=(i['Patient ID'], i['Gender'], i['Age'], i['Mobile']))
```

MS-SQL database returns the cursor value as dictionary type data, for this you need to specify the conversion.

Comment: thank you... and sorry.. didn't see your answer til now. Then, the time I wrote my question, when I didn't find any answer I just converted my work into MySQL instead of MS server; but next time I may benefit from your advice.. thanks!